# How to move angular code from my local to github?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

When i try to commit it displays the following,

On branch gh-pages
Untracked files:
        node_modules/max-buffer-exceeded-error/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present

Comment: You should not push `node_modules` into your repository. Use `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks Hitmands i am new to github,how to use .gitignore?

Comment: If you are also new to `git` and `version control softwares` I suggest you to have a look at [`https://git-scm.com/doc`](https://git-scm.com/doc), just few chapters and you'll learn about ignoring files, branching, committing, pushing, ecc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never commit `node_modules` to your repo. Create, if you not already have, a `.gitignore` file in the root of your project, and add `node_modules/`

Comment: How to add node_modules?

Comment: just put it on a newline in the file. Search for [.gitignore templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

I think you added node_modules folder. Run

```
git rm node_modules
```

to remove them from your repository.

After that operation, add node_modules to the `.gitignore` file.

Finally commit and push.

Comment: Thanks-Should i include .gitignore when creating repository?

Comment: Absolutely yes!